# saving contact bodies to be destroyed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

In my code I would like to destroy one of two contacted bodies. Within the beginContact the following method in CCPhysicsSprite is called:

```
-(void)contactMade:(CCPhysicsSprite*)contactedSprite {
int spriteTag1 = self.tag;
int spriteTag2 = contactedSprite.tag;

if (((spriteTag1 == 3) && (spriteTag2 == 4)) || ((spriteTag1 == 4) && (spriteTag2 == 3)) {

   CCPhysicsSprite* heroSprite = (CCPhysicsSprite*)[self getChildByTag:4];
    b2World* world;

    world->DestroyBody(heroSprite.b2Body);
    heroSprite.b2Body = NULL;
    [heroSprite.parent removeChild:heroSprite];
}
```

I get a signal SIGABRT pointing to

```
b2Assert(m_bodyCount > 0);
```

After searching on this issue. I read that the contact body has to be saved and destroyed after the timestep. How can I do this, given that I have set my contact conditions in the CCPhyscisSprite.

Comment: you need to add the to be destroyed bodies to an array, preferably in the class that runs the box2d world step. After the step destroy all bodies in the array and empty it. Tip: in http://www.koboldtouch.com you can destroy such bodies directly in the contact callback methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag ( like : isDead ... ) to your physical object and in collision event just change that flag value to TRUE .

```
-(void) CollisionBegin:(b2Fixture*)target With:(b2Fixture*) source
{    
    if ( target->GetBody()->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody)
    {
        yourCustomClass *temp = (yourCustomClass *)target->GetBody()->GetUserData();
        temp->isDead = true ;
    }
}
```

Then in update function after step get all physical world's object and find that specific object by flag ( Here : isDead ) , and destroy that .

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{

    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 3;

    world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

    // remove your box2d object here , after step function

    for ( b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; )
    {
        b2Body *baba = b->GetNext();
        if ( b->GetUserData() != NULL && b->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody)
        {
            yourCustomClass *t = (yourCustomClass *)b->GetUserData();
            if ( t->isDead )
            {
                world->DestroyBody(b);    // remove physical body
                [self removeChild:t];     // remove node from super layer
            }
        }
        b = baba ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could get a bit slow if there is a large number of bodies in the world, because it does that check every time step, and most of the time it will not find any bodies to destroy. Adding the object to a list (std::set is best) and then destroying whatever is in the list after the time step is more efficent for large worlds.